# Can I use my existing VM when deploying CF using BOSH

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

If my understanding is correct BOSH get all the vm it needs by making dynamic calls to vSphere or AWS. Can I pre-provision VM and then hand it to BOSH for deployment?

Comment: Could you share a little about your use case? BOSH is meant to handle provisioning, what reasons are you looking to provision yourself? Is there concerns, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely find more about BOSH on https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/bosh-users

Regarding the pre-provisioned VMs, not as far as I know. If you have a vm pre-provisioned, bosh doesn't interrogate an existing vm to get ip or other config info. If you have a pre-provisioned vm which you also have the same ip and config inside your deployment manifest, bosh will just go ahead and create a new vm and you would end up with 2 hosts with the same ip.

Bosh goes over whatever the deployment manifest says and creates new VMs. You should ONLY use bosh managed VMs. Because those VMs have meta data in the BOSH db and BOSH knows about their existence.